# Firefox transitions when adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Have a look at http://gull.calvin-evans.mixture.io/

When you click one of the big brown rectangles a class of "dropped" is applied with jQuery which changes the top position. This does not transition at all in the latest version of FF as it does in most other browsers and I have no idea why. When I use the in-browser debugger and add the class manually in the markup it bloody transitions! So bizarre. If anyone has any ideas on this is would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my CSS (less) for the record:

```
.card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s  top 0;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s  top 0;
    -o-transition: 0.6s  top 0;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s  top 0;
    transition: 0.6s  top 0;
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    &.one {
        z-index: 4;
        background: @brown1;
        background-size:100% auto;
        top: 0%;
        &.dropped {
            top: 90%;   
        }
    }
    &.two {
        z-index: 3;
        background: @brown2;
        top: 0;
        &.dropped {
            top: 85%;   
        }
    }
    &.three {
        z-index: 2;
        background: @brown3;
        top: 0;
        &.dropped {
            top: 80%;   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your js ? And try adding the 'dropped' class in a timeout : `setTimeout(function(){... add the class}, 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your JavaScript app (Or jQuery...).

When I added manually `onclick="this.className += ' dropped'"` it works correctly but I cannot say where exactly problem in script is, because you have a minified script.

Comment: Browsers do optimisations by grouping DOM/CSS manips. This can 'cancel' transitions, particularly if `display` or `visibiliy` is involved. Using a timeout (even with 0 delay) can give you control over what's going to be executed last, creating some sort of queuing (see [this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/understanding-javascript-timers/)). If it does not work try increasing the timeout delay (10, 20 and so on...) or using CSS animations. This is some sort of hack, for 'diagnosis' purpose. For us to find a better explanations, we need to see your js code @Calvin.

Comment: This case i where only translation is done. But I'm not sure about script is correct

Comment: @adjogima okay so I had tried wrapping it in a setTimeout() but it didn't work. I tried changing from jQuery to vanilla JS to add the class and it still didn't work. Tried the setTimeout thing and it still didn't work. But then I realised that the variable I was using to keep track of the current "card" was having one added it to it prematurely as I hadn't included the counter++ line in the setTimeout. As a result it was skipping the first card giving the appearance nothing was happening.. Doh!

Comment: Doh! Haha I was all like "browser optimisations" and "setTimeout queuing" : why do simple when you can do overcomplicated... Well, thanks for keeping us posted.